# How to combine testng index.html files got from multiple runs

Tags: testng

Here is the situation where  I am running Test suite 3 times(based on some param for some purpose) in a loop via main method,Each time I run the index.html is overridden , Is there any way I can merge all 3 runs into a single index.html?

Note:Tried of storing index.html for each run and concatenating them ,but the result is not impressive as its html file and the html elements are overlapping due to concatenation